# How to retrieve the value from Drop down list into the Controller in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have a div inside a form but I'm not quite sure how to retrieve the chosen value into the controller:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'system-users-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

<button id="abutton">Already a Supplier</button>
<br>
&nbsp;
&nbsp;

<div class="row" id="toshow" style="display:none" name="suppliers"> 
<?php $supplier = SupplierHead::model()->findAll();
   $list = CHtml::listData($supplier ,'head_id','head_name'); 
   echo $form->DropDownList($model,'party_id', 
   $list, array('prompt'=>'Select Supplier')); 
?> 
</div>



<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#abutton").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#toshow").css('display', 'block');
   });
});
</script>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>200)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Note that this row also belongs to another model. How would I retrieve this inside another controller?

Controller Code:

```
 public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new SystemUsers;
        $modelParties = new Parties;
        $modelPersons = new Persons;
        $supplierHead = new SupplierHead;
    //  $modelPR = new PartyRoles;
// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($invoice);

if (isset($_POST['SystemUsers']))
    {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['SystemUsers'];
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand("insert into parties (party_type_id) values ('1')")->execute();           
        $id = Yii::app()->db->lastInsertId;

        $_POST["SupplierHead"]["party_id"];
        $model->password = md5($model->password);
        $model->party_id = $id;
        $model->status = "Approved";
        $model->date_modified = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
        $email = $model->username;
        if($company != null)
            {

                Yii::app()->db->createCommand("insert into persons (party_id,email,company_name) values ('".$id."','".$email."','".$company."')")->execute();
            }
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand("insert into persons (party_id,email) values ('".$id."','".$email."')")->execute();
        Yii::app()->db->createCommand("insert into party_roles(party_id,role_id) values ('".$id."','2')")->execute();
  /*
        $valid = true; 
        $valid &= $model->validate(); 
        $valid &= $modelParties->validate(); 
              if($valid)
                {   
        $modelParties->save();
        $model->party_id = $modelParties->getPrimaryKey();  */

        if($model->save())
            echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                    window.alert('User Created')
                    window.location.href='create';  
                </SCRIPT>");

//      }
        else $this->redirect(array('views22','id'=>$model->id));
 }

$this->render('create',array(
  'parties'=>$modelParties,
  'model'=>$model,
));
```

}

Model for SystemUsers:

```
public function tableName()
{
    return 'system_users';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('username, password', 'required'),
        array('isLogin', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('date_modified','default',
          'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
          ),
        array('date_last_login','default',
          'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
          ),
        array('date_created','default',
          'value'=>new CDbExpression('NOW()'),
          ),
        array('status','default','value'=>'Approved'),
        array('user_role','default','value'=>'MEMBER'),
        array('isLogin','default','value'=>'1'),

        array('username', 'length', 'max'=>200),
        array('password', 'length', 'max'=>255),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
    );
}
```

**EDIT**

I added my model and the rest of the form to show you the confusion. The dropdown list div is value i'm trying to input into a different model and it does not exist as an attribute for system_users so It's not going through the POST.

Comment: Is filed name "party_id" exist in your table 'system_users' ?

Comment: yes, party_id is the primary key in system_users. I'm trying to retrieve the head_id from the dropdown list which exists from the supplier_head table

Comment: Ok see my answer,let me know if fix your issue.

Comment: you are still unable to fix your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that your model's attribute has a safe rule.
Second, in controller get a dump to see what have been sent via POST request. Do like below:

```
CVarDumper::dump($_POST,5678,true);
Yii::app()->end();
```

Third, find your dropdown element in the dump you have. 
In Yii, You can also get a post value like below:

```
Yii::app()->request->getPost('YOUR DROPDOWN NAME');
```

**UPDATE**

As I said first, You must make sure that your attribute is safe.
In your model add a rule like below:

```
array('THE NAME OF YOUR DROPDOWN','safe'),
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This helped a little, but I found out that my dropdown value is not even getting posted. I updated my question to show you the entire code structure.

I think the problem is that when I do a $_POST['SystemUsers'] to get the attributes from the form, the dropdown list isn't part of the attributes for system_user.

Comment: I understand what you mean about using 'safe' but I don't think you understand that the DROPDOWN is NOT a part of the model system_users so I can't add that to the rule.

Comment: Ow, Sorry. But a question, if your dropdown is not a part of your model why did you define it in view with model? I mean $form->DropDownList($model,'party_id'). Use CHtml instead of $form

Comment: If you want to do like what you wrote, you can easily add an safe attribute to your model. So what would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

@charlesisjan this depends on debugging also. Actually $_POST is an array with a collection of arrays, and further these arrays are a collection of key value pairs like

```
array(
    'key'=>'value'
)
```

First you need to ensure whether `party_id` is being submitted in the form. I am sure it is being submitted.
Now after

```
if (isset($_POST['SystemUsers']))
    {
```

use

```
CVarDumper::Dump($_POST,100,true);
die();
```

I am using a dummy code.
it will show you the $_POST array like

```
array ( 'User' => array ( 'username' => 'rafasd' 'password' => 'asdfas' 'email' => 'asd@yahoo.com' ) 'yt0' => '' )
```

in above code as user is itself an array so u can access the username as

```
$_POST['User']['username']
```

Now try to find out where does party_id is located in the $_POST array. When u find that u can access its value using above mentioned pattern

Answer (score 0):

you can get as :

```
 $id =  $_POST["SystemUsers"]["party_id"]
```

As per your code, drop-down name will be set as "Model_name[Field_name]".

In your action, you can see the line

```
$some_variable  = $_POST["SystemUsers"]; // SystemUsers is model name
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further? I tried putting these into my controller but I'm not getting any results.

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Hmm. I don't think I'm explaining my question correctly. The form has all the attributes for system_users model EXCEPT for the snippet I posted above. That one is for persons model. I'm trying to retrieve that value from the SystemUsers Controller, but none of the codes are working.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your

```
 $_POST["SupplierHead"]["party_id"];
```

with this

```
 $_POST["SystemUsers"]["party_id"];
```

in your controller action create,I think error is here!
Also if `party_id` is Your primary key then don't use in drop down, create new public variable in your model and use here in drop down.

Comment: how can i add another model inside my form? I want to call my supplier_head table

Comment: You need to only head_id, so in your SystemUsers model create a new public variable `public $headid;' and in your drop down replace this with `party_id`

Comment: In your action Create use this `$_POST["SystemUsers"]["headid"];`
 $supplierHead->primarykey